# Pyodbc driver/DSN not found AWS lambda - works on EC2

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using PYODBC inside AWS Lambda. I set up an EC2 instance and installed all dependencies and packages needed. I am able to query SQL within EC2 but not within Lambda.

Seems like I am missing a config or a library to set up the connections when packaging. I have copied the SQL driver in /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1 location. Copied the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files as needed. Copied the libtds and libodc* as well.

The error that I get when I package all the libraries and dependencies into lambda package is below:

```
[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

My odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini is below:

```
odbc.ini 
[DEV] 
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server 
Description = DEV 
Trace = No 
Server = abc.net,1234

odbcinst.ini 
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] 
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server 
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1 
UsageCount=1
```

I tried providing the DSN and also explicitly mentioning the Driver and Server name in pyodbc.connect. Still no luck!

Any help or direction would be appreciated!

TIA

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files? Do you have the driver specified correctly? Also, if you have a connection string, could you provide that? Perhaps there is an issue with that instead.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the information to that rather than here as a comment.

Comment: Is your odbcinst.ini really missing a line break? `Driver=` should be at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Formatting issue ... fixing it!

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app within Lambda.

Comment: Tried that as well missed providing that info, its empty.

Comment: @Sandesh Could you try taking the spaces out around the `=` in your `odbc.ini` file? Sometimes things can act funny due to spaces. Also, you do not have a `Database=dbname` in your `odbc.ini` file. That would be more likely the problem over a possible issue with spaces.

Comment: I tried with removing spaces as well :) odbc.ini need not have Database name I think. I have this whole setup working in Ec2! not able to package all into a lambda!

Comment: tried to get use the Driver and Server name explicitly without specifying the DSN, getting this error now 'IM004', "[IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Comment: @GordThompson Can I specify the DSN file name in the pyodbc.connect ?

Comment: @Sandesh - It depends on what you mean. If you mean the location of the odbc.ini file(s) then no, they are determined by the driver manager (unixODBC), but `odbcinst -j` will show you where it is looking. If you mean to create a separate file to define your DSN then you can do that and then use something like `pyodbc.connect('FILEDSN=/path/to/my.dsn')`.

Comment: I got this resolved by mentioning the exact path to the driver in pyodbc.connect

Answer (score 0):

After digging through multiple blogs and links, the answer is as simple as explicitly mentioning the location of driver when you connect using pyodbc.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1;Server=server,port;UID=uname;PWD=pwd;database=db_name;Encrypt=YES;TrustServerCertificate=Yes')
```

Comment: How did you install the driver in EC2? I'm having trouble getting that part set up.

Comment: you would have to copy the driver directly/manually.